# Days Calculation in influxdb

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I have given a field for getting the launch time of an instance in influxdb, but I need to get the no. of days from which the instance is running. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Are you having problem in getting "days from which the instance is running" (or) storing it to Influxdb?

Comment: I should get the no. of days from which that instance is running...

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=103073   Good luck!

Comment: Thanks.. but, I have the date and time... I need the number of days to be displayed in grafana

Comment: When you have lanch time & current time and know which programming language you are using to process these dates, I don't think it is big deal to calculate "number of days" when you have TWO dates.

Comment: I also thought so... But the time stamps influx gets and the date field I give are not of same type ..... I should look at the code and try to make changes in the script itself....

Comment: https://bpaste.net/show/9438feff37e3 This may help you.

Comment: Thanks @Luv33preet... Got it sorted.